# Return 401 for Custom Authrization

Tags: asp.net-core

how to return 401?

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
    AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
    PermissionsAuthorizationRequirement requirement,
    IEnumerable<PermissionsAuthorizeAttribute> attributes)
{
    // TODO: Check authentication succeeded or not.
    foreach (var permissionAttribute in attributes)
    {
        if (!await Authorize(context, permissionAttribute.RequiredPermissions))
        {
            context.Fail();
            return;
        }
    }
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This class is for Authorization and you can't set 401 status code from here.

This is how things work, you call `context.Fail()` in your `IAuthorizationHandler` and then based on whether your request has been authenticated or not `PolicyEvaluator` will call `Forbid` or `Challenge` for that authentication schema.

So you need to have a authentication handler which returns 401 on challenge.